# Child documents does not stored in separate collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I needed to have child documents in side paranet document. Expecting child document in a seperate collection.

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });
var parentSchema = new Schema({
children: [childSchema]
})
var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);
var parent = new Parent({ children: [{ name: 'Matt' }, { name: 'Sarah' }] })
parent.save(callback);
```

Here children document does not stored in the separate collections called 'childschemas'. It is always stored inside Parent collection itself. But i wanted to search child schema collections.

Am i miss anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified children to be stored in the document, just using a schema for validation. If you want subdocuments to be stored in a separate model you'd specify it as such:

```
children: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Model' }]
```

Note that Model is the name of a model, not a schema.

Comment: Thanks. We used this for referencing document. But We actually want to store them in a single save. Instead of saving children documents and update id in the children. We want save and update in a single call.

Comment: You don't have to store them separately. If you specify a reference this way, you can do for example `document.children = ['Children string']` and mongoose will take care of storing it correctly. To get the values again you'll have to use .populate();

Comment: Okay understood. I will try it.
Will it take care of all save and update method?

Comment: Yes, as far as you code goes just pretend it's a sub-document

Comment: Actually I would like to add that if you edit properties _in_ a referenced object you will have to call .save() oon it. But as long as you just add/remove documents to the array you should be fine. @FizerKhan did this answer work for you?

Comment: Yes. I understood. I want to edit the children properties. If i call save only on my parent document, It will not update the children properties.But add and removal of any children document will work on the parent document save. Is that right?